# KDbg on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Tags: 10.04, debugging

I wanted a good debugger gui for gdb and found that `KDbg` is the best one.
When I tried searching for it in Synaptic Package Manager I could not found it, then after a bit of googling found out that it was discontinued by Ubuntu guys.

Got a link [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1751278) pointing to [this repo](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/backports) but could not find it there also.

So my question is that is there a way I can download and install Kdbg on ubuntu 10.04 or Is there a better and newer alternative to it?

Any suggestions are appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: @psusi and others. Can you please let me know why the question is closed? The question is related to Ubuntu. Am I missing something.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KDbg is available from the Ubuntu repositories: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=kdbg&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

```
Package kdbg
lucid (devel): graphical debugger interface [universe] 
2.2.0-2ubuntu1: amd64 i386 
precise (devel): graphical debugger interface [universe] 
2.5.0-1: amd64 i386 
quantal (devel): graphical debugger interface [universe] 
2.5.1-1: amd64 i386 
raring (devel): graphical debugger interface [universe] 
2.5.1-1: amd64 i386
```

---Edit---

The KDbg is in the Ubuntu 10.04,Lucid Lynx, repositories. It should be installable via the package management (Synaptic,Apt,...). You should check your settings.

Ubuntu Community Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Comment: Thanks for the link. But when I start installing it gives an error about the other dependencies. Is there any way I can install it using apt-get or any other package manager so that all dependencies are automatically taken care of.

Comment: @abhi, yea... umm.. install it using apt-get?

Comment: @psusi I did not understood your last comment. Can you please explain. Thanks

Comment: @abhi, you type `sudo apt-get install somepackage`.

Comment: @psusi Thanks for clarifying that I do know that I just wrote apt-get just as a short form to point to using that command (in its full working form off course.) Do you have any idea how can I use it to install kdbg as currently it is not in package list for ubuntu.

Comment: @abhi, as this answer correctly states, yes, it is in the package lists.